# Proper way to update jsp content after a servlet call?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm looking for a way to dynamically update my jsp content, like an image, after servlet execution. The servlet would fetch the image and display this in a jsp "tag".

Is this possible? I'm eager to hear if it's also possible without page refresh. I have already made a Ajax that run the servlet perfectly.

I'm sorry if my question appear vague.

UPDATE:
Okey so I've used the session.Attribute to display some information and this code:

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.Text}"/>
```

But this only appears randomly if I log in and out. But I ofcourse want it to appear at all times.

I use `session.invalidate();` to make sure when I log in a new session is created.

Is there a way to dynamically update the c:out ?

2nd UPDATE. Solved it. Instead of toying with jsp. I just make an ajax call after the first login ajax call. That way I could use the session.attributes to "upload" the info on login.

Comment: Need more info what you trying to do. Once page loaded you can hook code to update page in any event if you don't like to refresh. But again need more info on what you trying to do to help you.

Comment: You would use Ajax...but you already know that, so not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Okey I'll try to elaborate; Once a user logs in, I wish to retrieve a image from my SQL and upload it on the page.

Comment: Just a side note: as you suspected, I think you won't be able to dynamically update the `<c:oout />`

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Instead of toying with jsp. I just make an ajax call after the first login ajax call. That way I could use the session.attributes to "upload" the info on login

Comment: If that solved the problem, accept this as the correct answer. Self-answering is fine, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer